# how to specify log format for supervisor stdout log?

Tags: python, supervisord

I have a process configured in supervisor as below. The module itself have its own logger in code. Normally we do not care the stdout_logfile.

But today I found there are some exception info in stdout_logfile (not captured by the logger in code). I want to know when did those exception happened. But the stdout_logfile did not have timestamp for each line. It seems have no format at all.

**So how can we config format for stdout_logfile in supervisor?**

```
[program:my_process]
environment=ENV=test
command=python my_process.py
directory=/home/me/
autostart=true
startretries=3
stopsignal=INT
stopwaitsecs=10
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/home/me/logs/my_process.stdout
```

Comment: Specifying the log format for supervisor has been a [*long* standing](https://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor/issues/553) and still active issue in their GitHub repo.

Answer (score 0):

in my case i solved this problem by using

```
stderr_logfile=/home/root/project/logfile_err.log
```

this scripts